# DSL modem connects to unknown IP address

Tags: windows-xp, adsl

I'm on day TWENTY...working with my IP provider to figure out this oddity. 
I wanted to upgrade my dsl speed with my provider, so they contacted our phone company to make the switch. Instead of an upgrade, I lost connection completely. So in the midst of my trouble shooting, I reset the modem to the factory defaults, unplugged my router and...my internet connection was restored...to the wrong service provider...no one seems to know WHO I'm connecting thru. My assigned IP address is a 
192.-.-.- address...the one I'm connecting to is a 50.-.-.-. I'm assuming it's an unassigned address from the phone company. I've gone back in and manually input my service providers info in to the dsl modem and it automatically disconnects me from the internet....clear it out and I'm up an running even though my provider doesn't see me connected to their server. Right now...I'm getting free internet and I wouldn't say a word EXCEPT I'm still connecting at the original speed. The phone company "claims" to have fixed the problem on their end, yet my modem STILL connects to this 50.-.-.- IP address which is not my providers. I SHOULDN'T be able to connect...I'm not inputting ANY user info or passwords. Any suggestions for the "tech's"? They're telling me that my connection is impossible, yet I'm still surfing daily.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to indentify the registered "owner" of the 50.x.x.x. address A site like [DomainTools](http://whois.domaintools.com/) can assist.  Once you know who the registered owner of the address or range is, you can speak to your ISP.

Have you been able to escalate the issue to a more senior tech?  I had a similar issue and anfter many calls, I reached a more senior person who quickly identified the issue.

Comment: I've worked with the team leaders on this and they're stumped as well. The 50 IP address is part of the original set assigned to the phone company, then it gets sketchy. It may or may not be part of the chunk of ip addresses that are supposed to be assigned to the dsl company. Frontier (phone company) says it's theirs, one of the dsl tech's says it's theirs. Frontier says they came to my come and spoke with someone at my home (they didn't), we later found out they went to the wrong house...but they still claim it's been resolved...someone else is getting free internet too apparently